# Regular expression to replace '.' at the start of the line

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to replace line numbers with dot(.) "123." using regular expression. for example the line is,

```
123. <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

Here i want to get rid off "123." which is at the start of the line.
At the moment the code i have that replace any number and dot(.) in anywhere in the line but i want to get rid off numbers and dot(.) only at the start of the line.
Here is my code,

```
<?php
$pattern = '/[0-9. |0-9.](?:\d{0})/';
$replacement = ' ';
$try= preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $line);
echo "\r\n" . html_entity_decode($try);
?>
```

I would appreciate if anyone can point me to the right direction. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code..

```
$line = '123. <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">';
$pattern = '/^[0-9]+\./';
$replacement = "";
$try= preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $line);
echo "\r\n" . html_entity_decode($try);
```

**Result**
`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">`

[**Codepad**](http://codepad.org/yWs7CBSt).

Comment: I tried both but it simply did not get rid off that "0. " i don't know why but ill dig up a little. hopefully find the answer to that and i will update... thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Why did your pattern not work?  You had two problems:

```
[0-9. |0-9.]
```

Brackets are a character class.  They mean "match one of any character".  So what this part of your regex does is match a single character that is a number, dot, space or |.

You appear to be trying to create a matching group.  In that case, you would need parentheses instead of brackets.  Something like this would do what you were trying to accomplish:

```
([0-9]+\.|[0-9]+\. )
```

That will match some digits followed by a dot, and possibly followed by a space.  However, you can make that much simpler:

```
[0-9]+\. ?
```

The `?` enables you to eliminate the long expression, because it means "maybe the pattern includes a space".

You could go even further, though:

```
\d+\.\s*
```

`\d` matches any digit, and `\s` matches any whitespace.  `*` means that you will match any amount of whitespace, rather than a single space.

Finally, you also had this in your pattern:

```
(?:\d{0})
```

I'm not sure what you were trying to do, but this says "match a group containing exactly zero digits".  It doesn't make much sense, and it isn't necessary either.

Your final pattern can simply be this:

```
'/^\d+\.\s*/'
```

One final addition was the `^` at the beginning.  This ensures that you only match numbers when they are at the beginning of a line.

Comment: I am not good at reg expression. your explanation really helped... thanks a mill...

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern:

```
$pattern = '/^\d+\.\s?/';
```

Comment: tried your code works for every line except the following line which is the start.  0. <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">; any idea how to fix it. thanks

Comment: @user1825190, that line should match perfectly fine.  Not sure what problem you are having.

Comment: It got rid off all the line numbers except for that specific line that start with "0. ".

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for any regular expression here, [`ltrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) will do:

```
$line = ltrim($line, "0123456789. ");
```

Comment: That would also impact lines that started without a number, but with a period or space.

Comment: ...or lines that continue with numbers right after the line number.

Comment: @Richard: Indeed. But the sample input does not look like this would happen. In any case, this answer attempts to address the OP's actual problem (better: my best guess of what it is) rather than their perceived problem.

Comment: tried your code works for every line except the following line.
0. <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> thanks

Comment: @user1825190: So what does it do for that line?

Comment: 0. <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> this is the first line.After using the code it remain the same. i mean it shows still "0. " at the start

Comment: @user1825190: Almost certainly that line includes non-printable characters at the beginning. Use `var_dump` and `bin2hex` on the string to see exactly what's going on and strip them.

Comment: after using this code,                      var_dump(html_entity_decode($line), bin2hex(html_entity_decode($line)));                                  0. <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">                                                           the above line remain the same and that is the only line. rest of the line looks like,                                       string(15) "2. <head>"
string(30) "322e20266c743b686561642667743b"

Answer (score 0):

Digits followed by a period at the start of a line would be:

```
^[0-9]+\.
```

Note escaping the period so it matches a period rather than any character.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)?

If you know that your lines begin with a number:

```
$initial_string = '123. <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">';
$desired_string = explode('.', $initial_string, 2)[1];
print $desired_string;
```

**Edit:** If you aren't sure if a line begins with a number or not:

```
$initial_string = '<html xmlns="http://wwww3org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">';
$initial_arr = explode('.', $initial_string, 2);

if (count($initial_arr)>0 && ctype_digit($initial_arr[0])){
    $desired_string = $initial_arr[1];
}else{
    $desired_string = $initial_string;
}
print $desired_string;
```

Comment: Why not do this?  Because it fails disastrously on any lines that don't start with a number.  Actually, a regex is the perfect tool for this job.

Comment: Improved it! Surely much longer than a regex but I dislike regular expressions mainly because the code is much more difficult to maintain.

Comment: Actually, your much longer, much more complicated code will be harder to maintain and more error-prone than a regex.

Comment: It's not matter of length if it is easy to maintain. It is matter of how easy and straightforward it is to understand it. I never use in my code regular expressions that someone else told me simply because if you don't write it yourself to understand why it works, you'll have a part in your code that is not clear to you. And this happens a lot with regular expressions. Someone found a regex online, includes it in the code and then cannot change it because she/he cannot understand it.

Comment: @Vasilis, I agree that using regexes without knowledge is dangerous.  But the answer is then learning how they work rather than avoiding them.  They are the clear, correct solution to many problems (including this one).  Regexes may look confusing at first, but a one line regex that takes a minute to figure out is better than dozens of lines of unnecessary code in an attempt to avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the dot (.) with a backslash (\) otherwise the dot matches any character.
So use "\." to match a dot and "." to match any character.